How can one combine iterables keeping only the first element with each index?
Let's say I have a number of iterables:
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]

How can I get only each element that is the first to appear at its index in any of the iterables? In this case:
[1, 2, 5, 6, 14]

Visualized:
[1, 2]
[_, _, 5, 6]
[_, _, _]
[_, _, _, _, 14]


Can you explain the logic

if we output n items we must ignore first n elements in all of iterators so the next (n+1)element from fist iterators that contain more then n elements


can it done in more functional style?

Sure, but I wouldn't. Davis Herring's approach is already lovely. Here's a "more functional" way, but more obscure to my eyes:
from itertools import zip_longest
SKIP = object()

def chain_suffixes(*iters):
    return (next(a for a in s if a is not SKIP)
            for s in zip_longest(*iters, fillvalue=SKIP))

print(list(chain_suffixes(
      [1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14])))

which prints

[1, 2, 5, 6, 14]

EDIT
BTW, "more functional" may be in the eye of the beholder. To my eyes, various forms of generator comprehension are just as "functional" as other ways of spelling it. At an extreme, it's possible to rewrite the above without using comprehensions at all, or even typing "def".
from itertools import zip_longest

SKIP = object()
not_SKIP = lambda x: x is not SKIP
first_not_SKIP = lambda s: next(filter(not_SKIP, s))
chain_suffixes = lambda *iters: map(
    first_not_SKIP,
    zip_longest(*iters, fillvalue=SKIP))


nice, i make something like this but use not object() but None and get some obscurity :) . thx

If you use None, it can get confused if None is one of the values in the iterated sequences. Using a module-specific singleton new object to mean "doesn't really exist" is the usual way around that. No iterable can contain SKIP unless it cheats by reaching into the module internals.

You can do just about anything with a generator:
def chain_suffixes(iters):
  n=0
  for it in iters:
    for x in itertools.islice(it,n,None):
      yield x
      n+=1


with chain_siffixes(*iters) - right! - can it done in more functional style?

You wouldn’t call this function with (*iters) but with (iters), which lets you have infinite iterators and so forth.  A functional style is of course always possible but here would not be very natural because of the chained dependencies on the previous size (especially if you also want to minimize copying).

i mean (*iters) as in chain is more right interface for my function :)

@qulinxao How so? You have your iterables in a list. With (*iters) you'd have to unpack that list for calling, and then it would get packed right back. Better to simply pass and use the list as-is.

Here is one way to do it:
out = []
for sub_list in m:
    out.extend(sub_list[len(out):])
# out = [1, 2, 5, 6, 14]

For each sub list, we only select those elements that starts with index len(out) to the end.

need for iterables :(

from itertools import islice

def chain_suffixes(iters):
    result = []
    for it in iters:
        result += islice(it, len(result), None)
    return result

iterables = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
print(chain_suffixes(iterables))

Attempt This Online!

Another, using zip to wrap elements in singleton tuples and the empty tuple as fill value:
from itertools import *

def chain_suffixes(iters):
    return map(next, map(chain.from_iterable, zip_longest(*map(zip, iters), fillvalue=())))

iterables = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
print(*chain_suffixes(iterables))

Attempt This Online!

Another, without itertools:
def chain_suffixes(iters):
    iters = list(map(iter, iters))
    while iters:
        for x in iters.pop(0):
            yield x
            for it in iters:
                next(it, None)

iterables = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
print(*chain_suffixes(iterables))

Attempt This Online!

Here's a fun one using islice to get the tails, chain to chain them, and compress and count to count the produced elements in order to get the islice starts. It runs without any Python interpretation (after setting it up).
def chain_suffixes6(iters):
    counter = count()
    starts = map(sub, counter, count())
    tails = map(islice, iters, starts, repeat(None))
    return compress(chain.from_iterable(tails), counter)

Explanation: Imagine you had a magical way to get the start indices for the tails. Then it would simply be this:
def chain_suffixes(iters):
    starts = <magic here>
    tails = map(islice, iters, starts, repeat(None))
    return chain.from_iterable(tails)

The start index for each iterable's tail is simply the count of how many elements we outputted so far, from all the previous iterables. To count them, I use a count iterator and use compress to move it along:
def chain_suffixes6(iters):
    counter = count()
    ...
    return compress(chain.from_iterable(tails), counter)

After the first iterable, we could just ask the counter for its next element. That would tell us how long that was. But then after the second iterable, the counter wouldn't just have counted the produced elements from the first iterable and the tail of the second. It would also have counted that one request for the current count! So we need to subtract 1. And the next time we ask, we need to subtract 2, etc. I do this compensation by subtracting another count():
    starts = map(sub, counter, count())

This actually begins with start = 0 - 0 for the first iterable's "tail". Note that this also already consumes the 0 from counter, so that in
compress(chain.from_iterable(tails), counter)

it only provides positive numbers, which are true, so that compress yields all elements from the chain of tails.

That solution is also the last version in this sequence of solutions. Each evolves from the one before it and they get more and more unusual, so it might be best to read them in order. (Though I btw wrote version 3 right away and then 4 and 5, then wrote 1 and 2 to perhaps help understanding, and then 6 when I realized I can "compress/count" the chain of tails instead of each tail.)
from itertools import *
from operator import sub

def chain_suffixes1(iters):
    start = 0
    for it in iters:
        counter = count(1)
        tail = islice(it, start, None)
        yield from compress(tail, counter)
        start += next(counter) - 1

def chain_suffixes2(iters):
    counter = count()
    for i, it in enumerate(iters):
        start = next(counter) - i
        tail = islice(it, start, None)
        yield from compress(tail, counter)

def chain_suffixes3(iters):
    counter = count()
    starts = map(sub, counter, count())
    for it in iters:
        tail = islice(it, next(starts), None)
        yield from compress(tail, counter)

def chain_suffixes4(iters):
    counter = count()
    starts = map(sub, counter, count())
    return chain.from_iterable(
        compress(tail, counter)
        for it in iters
        for tail in [islice(it, next(starts), None)]
    )

def chain_suffixes5(iters):
    counter = count()
    starts = map(sub, counter, count())
    tails = map(islice, iters, starts, repeat(None))
    tails_counted = map(compress, tails, repeat(counter))
    return chain.from_iterable(tails_counted)

def chain_suffixes6(iters):
    counter = count()
    starts = map(sub, counter, count())
    tails = map(islice, iters, starts, repeat(None))
    return compress(chain.from_iterable(tails), counter)

iterables = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
for f in chain_suffixes1, chain_suffixes2, chain_suffixes3, chain_suffixes4, chain_suffixes5, chain_suffixes6:
    print(*f(iterables), f.__name__)

Attempt This Online!
Silly oneliner version, I was just curious how that would look:
def chain_suffixes7(iters):
    return compress(chain.from_iterable(map(islice, iters, map(sub, counter := count(), count()), repeat(None))), counter)

And spreading that over multiple physical lines:
def chain_suffixes8(iters):
    return compress(
        chain.from_iterable(
            map(islice,
                iters,
                map(sub, counter := count(), count()),
                repeat(None))),
        counter
    )


Wow - that's clever! And sick ;-) I don't know whether it's trying to be obscure as possible, but it's a real head-scratcher. If it's not just trying to be a brain-buster, in chain_suffixes6 that compress isn't being used at all for its primary purpose (selecting a proper subsequence), it could be replaced by, e.g.,  the somewhat less obscure return map(operator.itemgetter(0), zip(chain.from_iterable(tails), counter)). Then it's clear that the values yielded by iterating over counter are irrelevant to this specific line - counter is being advanced for its effects on other lines.

@TimPeters Heh :-). I added more explanation now. Definitely wasn't trying to be obscure. Only trying to build an itertools contraption that then runs without Python interpretation (at the risk of being obscure, yes). That's a hobby for me, I do it for fun and for the challenge and for speed. And I actually think version 6 is quite clean, I'm very happy with it. Likely quite fast, too. That's one reason I prefer compress over map+itemgetter+zip, besides the shorter code. An internal truth check of an int is faster than mapping an itemgetter on a tuple.

(continuing) Yet another reason is that I want to showcase compress, as I think many people don't know it yet. I've used it with all-true "selectors" quite a few times, also for length-limiting one iterable by another. Just yesterday I came up with yet another neat usage, I might share that via a new question.

You can iterate over the lists in reverse and replace a slice each iteration
lists = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]

result = lists[-1]
for lst in lists[-1::-1]:
    result[:len(lst)] = lst

print(result) # [1, 2, 5, 6, 14]


You can also use reduce:
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda a,b: a + b[len(a):], m)

Out[33]: [1, 2, 5, 6, 14]


need for iterables :(

@qulinxao sorry I missed that. Of course this wont work
